# in HTML5, do you have to have a main element when creating a web page?

Tags: web, element, html, program-entry-point

When using HTML5, do you have to have a main element when creating a web page and if so, what is the maximum amount you can use?

Comment: well i have an exam soon and im going through my past papers and the question is, "one of the following statements about the use of the HTML5 main element is true.

Comment: a) A web page can have zero or any number of main elements.
b) A web page must have only one main element.
c) A web page can have zero or one main elements.

Comment: you should read the [**w3c html5 spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#a-quick-introduction-to-html)

Comment: It depends whether you are going by the W3C HTML5 spec or the WHATWG HTML Living Standard.

Comment: [**per Mozilla: `<main>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is the 'C'

look at:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is expected that the main element serve as diversionary element, like the header, nav, and footer. So I think it should really only be used once per page. Using markup similar to this.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <!-- Page Title -->
        </header>
        <nav>
            <!-- Primary Menu -->
        </nav>
        <main>
            <!-- Primary Content -->
        </main>
        <footer>
            <!-- Stuff at the Bottom -->
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```